# Separate numbers from characters in a variable, with inconsistent length -R

Tags: r, substring

I am trying to calculate months of experience, but currently my variable looks something like the below, where years and months are in the same column.

```
2 yrs 1 mo
1 yr 1 mo
2 yrs 4 mos
less than a year
10 mos
```

I'd like to separate the years and months from each other so I can then calculate total months of experience. My attempts so far have been inelegant, and `substring` hasn't been very helpful, as the length is not consistent. Any idea of how I could do so?

**EDIT**:
For `less than a year`, I'm thinking to substitute it with 11 months

Comment: @akrun I've updated the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do the extraction based on regex lookaround with `str_extract` and then calculate the 'total_month'.  The `less than a year` is changed to '11 mo' as updated in the OP's post

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
   mutate(col1 = replace(col1, col1 == 'less than a year', '11 mos'),
          month = as.numeric(str_extract(col1, "\\d+(?= mo)")),
          year = replace_na(as.numeric(str_extract(col1, "\\d+(?= yr)")), 0), 
          totalmonth = month + year * 12)
#         col1 month year totalmonth
#1  2 yrs 1 mo     1    2         25
#2   1 yr 1 mo     1    1         13
#3 2 yrs 4 mos     4    2         28
#4      11 mos    11    0         11
#5      10 mos    10    0         10
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `extract`

```
dat %>%
    mutate(col1 = case_when(col1 == 'less than a year' ~ '0 yr 11 mos',
           str_detect(col1, '^\\d+\\s+mo')~ str_c('0 yr ', col1), TRUE ~ col1)) %>%
    extract(col1, into = c('year', 'month'),   "^(\\d+)\\s*yrs?\\s*(\\d+).*",
             convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(totalmonth = month + year * 12)
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c("2 yrs 1 mo", "1 yr 1 mo", "2 yrs 4 mos", 
"less than a year", "10 mos")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Brilliant, ```str_extract``` makes more sense that ```substring``` here